# Strange warning when starting R under OS X

Tags: r, macos

On running RGui, it gives me the following prompt:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[R.app GUI 1.68 (7202) x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0]

[History restored from /Users/sunqingyao/.Rapp.history]

2016-05-09 08:49:53.286 R[472:6120] -deltaZ is deprecated for NSEventTypeMagnify.  Please use -magnification.
```

Everything seems OK expect for the last line. However, when I type several commands such as `example(plot)`, all of them work properly. This warning remains after I reinstalled R following the [official document](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Uninstalling-under-OS-X).

Comment: Did you install 32 bit or 64 bit R?

Comment: @MaxPD I've installed the 64-bit version

Comment: Uninstall and try the 32-bit. Check if you get the same warning. Refer to : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/

Comment: 32 bit R for version 3.0.0 on OSX? Really?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm running 64bit with no issues. Here's the output when staring it up in Terminal. Note the difference that my history isn't being restored like yours, so maybe try deleting the history file before starting up R. ie:

```
rm /Users/sunqingyao/.Rapp.history
```

I'm guessing there's a conflict there from your old version :

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.


Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or

'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.

Type 'q()' to quit R.
```

Here's my system info, in case it helps you:

> System Version: OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
>
> Kernel Version: Darwin 15.4.0
>
> Boot Volume: MBPr
>
> Boot Mode: Normal
>
> Computer Name: rossMBPr
>
> User Name: Ross ****** (ross)
>
> Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
>
> System Integrity Protection: Enabled
>
> Time since boot: 10 days 19:19

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your post better. Starting up in R GUI does give the history restore note, but not the deprecation note. Is there a package called "NSEventTypeMagnify" that you're running? If so, I'd say your problem is just that the "deltaZ" call is overlapped between 2 packages, so R is just telling you to be careful of that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've fixed this problem by using Time Machine. Although I still don't know what **was** wrong, it doesn't matter now :)

Comment: As in, you've gone back to an older version of R to fix the problem? Or you managed to get 3.3.0 (64 bit version) working properly?

Comment: R 3.3.0 (64-bit version) works properly on my computer now